# Unity Проблема анимации двойного прыжка

Tags: unity3d, анимация, 2d

Здравствуйте делаю небольшую игру на Unity 2Д платформер,все шло хорошо,пока не появилась проблема,сам двойной прыжок я сделал,и анимации прыжка работает хорошо,только мне нужно чтобы после второго прыжка проигрывалась анимации двойного прыжка,а не просто анимации прыжка,я прописал if(rb.velocity.y > .1f)
State = movementstate.jumping
И логически если я укажу вместо jumping doublejumping будет работать одна из анимации, что мне тогда сделать?

Comment: Не совсем понял вопрос. Приложи скрин аниматора и код к вопросу